# An HTTP request to the Yelp API returns a missing parameter error

Tags: c#, yelp

I try to retrieve some information from Yelp API for a UWP app. As they say [here](https://www.yelp.co.uk/developers/documentation/v2/authentication), I need to pass some parameter as header for a HTTP request, and then perform a Json request [using this link](https://www.yelp.co.uk/developers/documentation/v2/search_api). I know how to parse a Json file once I get it, but I have no idea how to get access to this file.

If for example I put `https://api.yelp.com/v2/search?term=food&location=San+Francisco&oauth_consumer_key=MYKEY&oauth_token=MYTOKEN&oauth_signature_method=hmac-sha1` this link on my browser

it return `{"error": {"text": "One or more parameters are missing in request", "id": "MISSING_PARAMETER", "field": "oauth_signature"}}`

How should I enter this `oauth_signature`?

Comment: As it says, did you put your OAuth key in the header? You can't make straight requests to this through your browser, as you need to supply headers for authentication. You can do this through an application called Fiddler, or through code.

Comment: You should probably clean up the title and the tags, because they make no sense. The only question I see is "which parameter is missing from my URL"? And the error message clearly says `oauth_consumer_key`

Comment: Thanks to you two, I have reached another problem then with the `oath_signature`

Answer (score 1):

According to their [specification](https://www.yelp.co.uk/developers/documentation/v2/authentication):

> Each request must contain the following OAuth protocol parameters:
>
> oauth_consumer_key Your OAuth consumer key (from
> Manage API Access).
>
> oauth_token    The access token obtained (from Manage
> API Access).
>
> oauth_signature_method    hmac-sha1
>
> oauth_signature   The
> generated request signature, signed with the oauth_token_secret
> obtained (from Manage API Access).
>
> oauth_timestamp   Timestamp for the
> request in seconds since the Unix epoch.
>
> oauth_nonce   A unique string randomly generated per request.

add the required field in your request and see what response you get. here you are missing `oauth_timestamp`, `oauth_nonce`, and `oauth_signature` fields in the request.

Comment: I do not understand how I can provide a `oath_signature_method` through the url, sorry this is the first time I do those things

Comment: sorry for late reply. was little out of touch. hope you have solved this by now. just FYI  the valve of  oauth_signature_method  will be "hmac-sha1"(as they described in spec).